# good Ubuntu/Debian distro for a development/coding VM?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, software-rec, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a Windows laptop, but I like to use Linux as a development/coding environment. Currently I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04 as a guest OS with VirtualBox. Some of the issues with this setup are:

- I need a lighter-weight distro - Ubuntu installs too many extraneous packages
- I like to work in VirtualBox's "seamless" display mode - GNOME Terminal is the app I use the most. I'd like to find a window manager which gives me more vertical real estate. The GNOME desktop manager (the classic version) works pretty well, but I don't need the top menu bar or bottom task bar, and I could do with smaller title bars on windows.

Any suggestions on windows manangers, configuring GNOME or other Debian/Ubuntu compatible distros?

Answer (score 6):

If your Linux VM is just for development, why do you need a desktop environment (or even X) on it?

You could run a VM without X (and all the baggage that comes with X) and connect to it with an ssh client (putty.exe).  You can run multiple ssh connections to the VM and/or if you have GNU Screen or similar installed on the VM then you can have multiple terminal sessions inside the one ssh connection (you can also detach and re-attach to them at will).

If you want a stripped-down debian/ubuntu system then the easiest way to get it is to install the debian base system into a VM and then install **only** the packages you actually need with apt-get or aptitude or whatever.

If you need to run GUI Linux applications, there are X servers available for MS Windows, including free versions (it's been many years since i've needed anything like this so i can't recommend any) - this would allow you to run the GUI app on linux and have the program's window display on your MS Windows desktop.

Comment: actually GNOME Terminal is one of the main reasons for the graphical component; I haven't found a comparable tabbed terminal emulator on Windows

Comment: For a tabbed terminal emulator, I have seen [ConEmu](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/) being recommended on Super User.

Comment: Gnome Terminal is one of the Linux GUI applications you could run using a Windows X Server.

Comment: Hm, I'm not following, why would you not need a desktop environment/X just because you do development? Doesn't that depend entirely what you are developing and what tools you use?

Comment: That is why I asked it as a question, rather than made a statement.  The question highlighted the possibility that X is not or may not be necessary for development work.  user5402 also expressed a desire for a lighter-weight distro because "Ubuntu installs too many extraneous packages".  Getting rid of X and Unity and gnome and so on is an easy way to get a lighter-weight linux VM.

Comment: I see, and of course, there is no doubt in my mind that the Linux console is much faster than for example GNOME Terminal under X and Metacity. It is worth the effort to be as fluent as possible in "both worlds" so you're always ready for whatever challenge you are up against.

Answer (score 2):

You could do with a minimal Debian/Ubuntu install, by individually selecting the packages you want.

But... Do you really need a GUI within the guest? You are better off ssh'ing to it using PuTTY and copying files from/to the VM using WinSCP or VirtualBox's shared folders.

If you do need graphical apps, [Cygwin has a X server](http://x.cygwin.com/).

Comment: yes I have used Xming but I've had problems with copy/paste from Xming to Windows.